# Node/React: How to handle jQuery AJAX when rendering on server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have a small webapp in Node/Express that renders initial HTML server side with react-dom. The page is then populated client side with a `$.ajax` call to the API inside `componentDidMount`. The HTML loads immediately, but there's no useful content until React starts and completes that GET.

This is wasteful. It would be better to hit the API while rendering the initial HTML. But. I don't know a clean way to implement this. Seems like I could get what I want by declaring a global `$` in node with a stubbed `get` method, but this feels dirty.

**How do I implement `$.ajax` when rendering a React component server side?**

The code is public on Github. [Here's a component](https://github.com/jtschoonhoven/podcastapp/blob/09f6528880ca8a8b967fa5c2fd7857464be00b9d/app/components_jsx/show/episodes.jsx) with `$.get` and [here's my API](https://github.com/jtschoonhoven/podcastapp/blob/c88c30133d06a267606c3625ec32736ab30b287f/routes/api.js).

Comment: can you inject the fetched value as the default state upon printing?

Comment: @dandavis I'll give that a try. If you know an example of someone doing that in an isomorphic way I would love to see it.

Answer (score 3):

- componentDidMount doesnt run on the server, it runs only client side for the first render, so the ajax request will never happen on the server. You should do it in a static method (there are other ways of do it)
- It would be better if you choose superagent or axios - that can made ajax requests client and server side
- You then have to put the result of the ajax request as the initial state on a global variable.

It's better if you follow some repos, like this:

See https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solved this.

1. Moved my ajax out of componentDidMount so that it *is* called while rendering initial HTML on the server.
2. Declared my own global `$` in Node with a `get` method that calls the router directly. This is what it looks like:

   ```
   global.$ = {
       get: (url, cb) => {
           const req = {url: url};
           const res = {
               send: data => cb(data),
               status: () => {
                   return {send: data => cb(data)};
               }
           };
           return api_router(req, res);
       }
   };
   ```

**Some caveats**

- If this feels like a questionable hack to you, that's ok. It feels like a questionable hack to me too. I'm still open to suggestions.
- @stamina-loop's suggestion of replacing jQuery's AJAX with module that works for both the server and client is a good one that would solve this problem. For most people I would recommend that approach. I chose not to because it seemed wasteful to go over the network just to call a route handler that is adjacent in code. Could be made less wasteful with a fancy nginx config that redirects outbound API calls back to the same box without making a round trip. I'm thinking on that.
- I've since learned that using jQuery alongside React is likely to cause problems. I'll be replacing it with something else down the road.
- For most use cases it will still make sense to keep the AJAX in componentDidMount and to load initial HTML without it. That way time-to-first-byte is as low as possible. The types of things that are loaded from restful APIs are usually not needed for SEO and are things that users are used to waiting a few extra milliseconds for (Facebook does it so can you).

Comment: This is a great point about when isomorphic JS can be taken too far when it's not necessary. Facebook does indeed do an initial load and then serves things up fast enough so as not to harm the user experience.